# html scraper using javascript from localhost

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a mobile application in my localhost using html, css and js. I want to bring the table of the following page
http://www.sleague.com/competitions/s-league/table

I want bring the table of that page(Point table) as it is. I've used a code which I'd found in sof but haven't got the html data. The code is as follows

```
function stripScripts(s) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = s;
    var scripts = div.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var i = scripts.length;
    while (i--) {
        scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
    }
    return div.innerHTML;
}
function loadTest () {
    alert("Inserted");
    $.get('http://www.sleague.com/competitions/s-league/table', function (data) {
        alert(stripScripts(data));        
    });
    alert("Done");
}
```

The code is running but the html I need from the page is not coming when I'm at localhost. What to do? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the [global AJAX error handler](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) in jQuery to see the error message.

In a nutshell, you can only load documents from the same domain ([same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)).

Comment: I haven't got any error while I've done it using $.ajax() method. I want to know what's the problem of that code so that the data is not coming :(

Comment: Are you saying "it works when I use $.ajax() but it doesn't work when I use $.get()"?

Comment: Actually the data is not coming for that link, I've tested with www.google.com and it worked but data from current url is coming using both ajax() and get(). Please let me know the solution, I'm in deep trouble :(

Comment: Current url means that url-- 'http://www.sleague.com/competitions/s-league/table'
Can you please give me the full code of the scrapper? I need the html of the page only, not any kind of scripts of that page. Thanks in advance

Comment: What confuses me is that this kind of access never works; not for google.com nor anything else. Browsers simply don't allow it. Can you please create a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/ which shows how you managed to get it to work with google.com?